# Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong with this Python login screen?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating the login screen for a Python email client, here is my code so far:

```
import imaplib # import the imap library
from tkinter import * #import everything from the tkinter library (for use with gui)


global user
global pword
global root

def LoginClick():
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('elwood.yorkdc.net')
    mail.login(user, pword)
    LoginClick.mainloop()

root = Tk() #creates new window
root.title('Login') #sets title of window
root.configure(background='black') #change background colour of window

instruction = Label(root, text='Please Login\n') #Creates label
instruction.configure(background='black', fg='white') #Configuring label style
instruction.grid(sticky=E) #Sticks to eastern edge

userL = Label(root, text='Username: ')
userL.configure(background='black', fg='white')
pwordL = Label(root, text='Password: ')
pwordL.configure(background='black',fg='white')
userL.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
pwordL.grid(row=2, sticky=W)

user = Entry(root)
pword = Entry(root, show='*')
user.grid(row=1, column=1)
pword.grid(row=2, column=1)

loginB = Button(root, text='Login', command=LoginClick)
loginB.grid(columnspan=2, rowspan=2, sticky=W)
root.mainloop()
```

When I run the module and enter my credentials into the gui I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marcus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Marcus\Desktop\Networking\IMAP.py", line 11, in LoginClick
    mail.login(user, pword)
  File "C:\Users\Marcus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 588, in login
    typ, dat = self._simple_command('LOGIN', user, self._quote(password))
  File "C:\Users\Marcus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 1180, in _quote
    arg = arg.replace('\\', '\\\\')
AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Am I on the complete wrong track with how this should be done in Python or is this a simple error to fix? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be passing the wrong kind of data to the imaplib library. It's expecting an object with a `replace` method, and you're giving it a `Entry`, which evidently does not have that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the documentation about this widget is [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.html)

I guess you wanna retrieve the value you passed to this widget. you can try with the `.get()` method which does that.

Comment: okay so changing mail.login(user, pword) to mail.login(user.get(), pword.get()) seemed to fix the issue, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help! Feel free to upvote and accept the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, since I have no experience with `imaplib` or `tkinter`, but this appears to be your problem:

```
mail.login(user, pword)
```

If you check the type of `user` and `pword`, they'll be `Entry`s.

`imaplib` however appears to require those arguments be objects with a `replace` method; probably a string.

If `Entry`s are text fields, you probably need to grab the text from the field and pass that instead of passing the whole `Entry` objects.